# How to check and enable Action in a UIAlertController only if the textfield is not empty?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uialertaction

I'm trying to figure out how to keep the Action Button disabled until the user enters some text in, at which point the button would be enabled again. I've been searching around, and some people are suggesting to use Observers? Would that be the best way to go?

Cheers!

```
   @objc func addExercise() {
            var textField = UITextField()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Exercise", message: "Please name your Exercise...", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Exercise", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                //Add Exercise to database.
                //Append exercise to selected workout object.
                let exercise = Exercises()
                exercise.exerciseName = textField.text!
                try! self.realm.write {
                    self.selectedWorkout?.exercise.append(exercise)
                    self.loadExercises()
                }
            }

            alert.addTextField { (alertTextField1) in
                alertTextField1.delegate = self
                alertTextField1.placeholder = "Bench Press"
                alertTextField1.text = textField.text
                textField = alertTextField1
            }

            alert.addAction(addAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using notification is a way but long work instead you can use simple delegate method or action method of textfield which is much easier as follow:

```
    weak var buttonActionToEnable: UIAlertAction?

    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField1) in
                    alertTextField1.delegate = self
                    alertTextField1.placeholder = "Bench Press"
                    alertTextField1.text = textField.text

                    alertTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
                }

    self.buttonActionToEnable = addAction
    addAction.isEnabled = false

    @objc func textFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {

          let textfield = sender as UITextField
          self.buttonActionToEnable?.isEnabled = textfield.text.count > 0
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but do you mind explaining how I would reference the "alertTextField1" inside the textFieldChanged #selector in order to set a condition for the textfield since it's out of scope?

Sorry if I'm asking a dumb question here, I'm still relatively new to programming.

Comment: Updated answer pls check

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.